# Limit is taken on a Binomial distribution ($p_n,n$) in this exercise but not on the Poisson($\lambda$) where $\lambda = np_n$. What did I miss?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

The wording for this exercise is confusing me a bit. Any clarity would be helpful!

Let $X_n$ be Binomial B($p_n,n$) with $\lambda=np_n$ being constant. Let $A_n$ = {$X_n \geq$ 1}, and let Y be Poisson($\lambda$). Show that $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞} P(X_n=j\,|\,A_n) = P(Y = j\,|\,Y \geq 1)$.

How $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}$ be taken on only one side of that last equation while keeping $\lambda\;(=np_n)$ constant?

Comment: $p_n$ is taken as $\frac {\lambda} n$. So $X_n \sim B(\frac {\lambda}n ,n)$.

Comment: Does $P(X_n=0)=(1-p_n)^n=(1-\lambda/n)^n$ look familiar?

Comment: @Kavi Geez, right. I was simply plugging the $np_n$ to replace the $\lambda$ in the Poisson distribution. Reframing it that way makes much more sense. Thanks.